# running a script on remote machine from local machine

Tags: unix

i want to run a sript that is present in local machine,but it should perform operations on remote machine.

i have already generated public-private keys,so no password authentiaction is required.

Answer (score 1):

Run the shell on the other side, and send the script through.

```
ssh user@host bash < script.sh
```

Comment: is it bash or 'bash -s'?

Comment: `-s` is not required except under specific conditions.

Comment: Note: this way you force `bash` to be the interpreter, any shebang is ignored; if the script required another interpreter, the command would have to be adjusted. +1 though.